# Best way to bind two select elements in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, select

What's the simplest way to bind two `select` elements in a form, such that the second `select` element has `option` elements related to the first choice?

Is there a direct method in jQuery?

Comment: @BenBarden: Maybe the question makes more sense now ^^ :P

Comment: Ahhh.  Much better.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your initial main select, create several select elements. Hide these sub-selects and don't give them a name attribute but give them a class that is the same as the main select's values.

```
<select class="main" name="name_of_main_select">
    <option value="value1-of-main-select">Value 1</option>
    <option value="value2-of-main-select">Value 2</option>
</select>

<select style="display:none" class="sub-select value1-of-main-select">...</select>
<select style="display:none" class="sub-select value2-of-main-select">...</select>
```

Then attach a change event to the main select where the value selected will be the same as the class attribute of it's corresponding select. Based off the value show the select and give it a name attribute.

```
$('select.main').change(function({
    $('select.sub-select').removeAttr('name').hide();
    $('select.'+$(this).val()).show().attr('name','sub_select_name');
});
```

**Update:** I made sure that the sub selects were hidden and that they weren't given a name each time the main select was changed.

Answer (score 3):

When you select an option on a select list, the "onchange" event will fire. So, using jQuery or native JS, you can bind the change event to the first Select such that it will update the options of the second select.

http://jsfiddle.net/aaronfrost/kxdUb/

Answer (score 1):

You could also use json in a data attribute.

HTML

```
<select id="first">
    <option data-second='{ "names" : [{"name":"jack"},{"name":"john"},{"name":"joe"}]}'>Names</option>
    <option data-second='{ "names" : [{"name":"Porsche"},{"name":"Ferrari"},{"name":"Mercedes"}]}'>Cars</option>
    <option data-second='{ "names" : [{"name":"Blue"},{"name":"Red"},{"name":"White"}]}'>Colors</option>
</select>
<select id="second"></select>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first").change(function(){
        $("#second option").remove();

        var names = $("#first option:selected").data('second').names;
        var newoptions = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
            newoptions+="<option value=" + names[i].name + ">"+ names[i].name +"</option>";                            
        }
        $("#second").append(newoptions);
    });        
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kamikazefish/kmQ7R/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making it an onchange function from the first select, which calls show() or hide() on the options of the second select (and resets it, so that it's not left sitting on a hidden option).

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juzerali/ppuWz/) too.

It is similar to Aaron Frost's example, except that it also puts values into your  option elements.